# Java split input

Tags: java, text-processing

I am trying to read in a command and a name. For example "name:" + "username" and I want to add the username to an arraylist. I am trying to split the input, so that I have a name variable and a username variable as shown below:

```
public void run() {
    String line;
    try {
        while(true) {
            line = input.readLine();
            String[] temp;
            temp = line.split(":");

            //checks different input from the client
            //checks to see if the client wants to terminate their connection
            //removes the client's name from the list

            if("name:".equals(temp[0])) {
                users.add(temp[1]);
                output.println("OK");
            }
            else {
                broadcast(name,line); // method in outer class - send messages to all
            }
        } // end of while
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
} // end of run()
```

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: Please check the resulting indentation and other formatting of code samples you post. (I fixed this one up already.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` swallows the separator, so you need to change this:

```
            if("name:".equals(temp[0])){
```

to this:

```
            if("name".equals(temp[0])){
```

Also, this:

```
                bc(name,line); // method  of outer class - send messages to all
```

seems a bit odd, in that it refers to a variable named `name`, but nothing in your posted snippet declares that variable, or (aside from this line) refers to it.